# most efficient way to do background colour change on hover with jquery 1.4+?

Tags: jquery

I remember looking at this a year ago and there were some plugins and a jquery ui method, but it's always worth asking - what's changed?

what's the most efficient/lightweight method/plugin for fading background colors on hover?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say the answer hasn't changed, still the [jQuery color plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color), unless you're including [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) already, in which case you don't need the plugin anymore.  The plugin is 3.6kb fully uncompressed, that's *pretty* small once gzipped (~1.45kb, even without minification).

Answer (score 1):

The "proper" way would to be use browser built-in CSS transitions:

```
    #test {
      background-color: red;
        transition: background-color 1s;
        -webkit-transition: background-color 1s;
        -moz-transition: background-color 1s;
        -o-transition: background-color 1s;
    }
    #test:hover {
        background-color: blue;
    }
```

Supported currently (AFAIK) in Webkit browsers, Opera 10.5 and coming to Firefox 4.

There is a small jQuery plugin, which adds supprt for other browsers: http://weston.ruter.net/projects/jquery-css-transitions/ (however it hax not been updated for over a year and I haven't used it myself)

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready(function()
{
        $("div:first").mouseover(function () {
          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 0.33);
        });
        $("div:first").mouseout(function () {
          $(this).fadeTo("slow", 1);
        });
});